# Sorting JSON response alphabetically in Swift

Tags: json, swift

I'm struggling with some code I'm playing with at the minute to sort the response alphabetically. Everything I try, it keeps flagging various errors and build issues.

My code currently runs:

```
class Category {
    var name = "Category"
    var offences = [Offence]()
    required init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
    func addOffence(data: JSON) {
        let offence = Offence(data: data)
        offences.append(offence)
    }
    var imageName: String {
        return name
    }
}
```

Any ideas where I can slot it in?

Comment: The code just shows how you present your data in collectionView, no so called `Sorting JSON response alphabetically`

Comment: Please delete this code (it is irrelevant to the question) and show the sort algorithm you are using in `getData`.

Comment: Apologies, I had the wrong controller copied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to update this previously...

So in order to sort the API response, I simply amended the API request to `sort by Active desc` and that achieves the result I was looking for.